# Border box not working when width and height of a div is assigned through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `<div>` with `border:1px solid red;` and `box-sizing:border-box;`. The **width** and **height** of the `<div>` is assigned using JavaScript (so that user can switch from portrait to landscape).

```
$("#cloud").width(width).height(height);//width=260.16,height=397.44
```

The problem is that box-sizing property is not working. It always adds 2px(border) to the height and width of the div.

What I have tried:

1. Assigned box-sizing using JavaScript, still not working.
2. If we assign **width**,**height** and **box-sizing** using CSS, it's works fine.
3. Tested in chrome and edge.

So how can I create a border-box div where user specifies the width and height?

Note: I'm writing all the Javascript inside the JQuery global function `jQuery( function(){ .. });`

Here is the JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/af1ohuxv/6/

Comment: pls post your HTML also

Comment: I tried and it works as expected. Can you please add a jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: @cdoshi added Jsfiddle. Please take a look

Comment: I looked at your jsfiddle. It looks fine Border is infact 1px as you want

Comment: The problem is border-box not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the docs of `width()`, it is clearly stated that

> Note that `.width("value")` sets the content width of the box regardless of the value of the CSS box-sizing property.

Same goes for `height()`. Not sure, what's the expected end result, but you wanted to use `innerWidth()` and `innerHeight()` (or `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()`) instead:

```
$("#cloud").innerWidth(width).innerHeight(height);
```

Comment: @Michel -- That's surprising. Please reproduce the problem in a fiddle or SO snippet. I'll take a look and suggest appropriate enhancements then.

Comment: Sure. And I'm writing the Javascript inside the jQuery global function, jQuery(function(){...}); Is that be a problem?

Comment: @Michel -- Ideally, enclosing the code in `jQuery(function() { ... })` shouldn't cause this issue. But that will be clear when you provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score -1):

You can approach it with .css() for example

```
$("#cloud").css("width","400")
```

or with array

```
$("#cloud").css({"width:"+width,"height:"+height})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/efkiss/af1ohuxv/12/

Comment: this doesn't assigning the width and height :(